# GUN.js causes build warning: Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: node.js, webpack, gun

I have GUN.js on my app, and it's causing this troublesome warning. How do I clear up this warning?

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/gun/gun.js 6:17-29
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
 @ ./src/components/MessageHandler.js 7:0-26 9:14-17
 @ ./src/App.js 20:0-61 230:37-51
 @ ./src/index.js 7:0-24 13:33-36

1 warning has detailed information that is not shown.
Use 'stats.errorDetails: true' resp. '--stats-error-details' to show it.

webpack 5.67.0 compiled with 1 warning in 174 ms
```

I've tried both `import Gun from 'gun/gun'` and `import Gun from 'gun'`.

Comment: got the same problem ```Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression```

Answer (score 2):

This bug should be fixed on the latest GitHub main.

It seems related to

[How to access SEA module in GUNJS without using dynamic require in React Native expo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70904956/how-to-access-sea-module-in-gunjs-without-using-dynamic-require-in-react-native/70962207#70962207)

(Please don't delete my post, I'm not a mod here, I'm just an OSS author trying to help out, I don't have time to figure out all the rules, I don't want to close or delete other people's Questions cause that makes me look bad. If others want to, they can, but until then, people need their questions answered. Thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

The solution is in the issue https://github.com/amark/gun/issues/743. It was sufficient for me to add `noParse` to WebPack config.

```
module: {
        noParse: /gun\.js$/,

...

}
```