# How to access SEA module in GUNJS without using dynamic require in React Native expo

Tags: react-native, expo, gun

So I've started this new project using **React Native(Expo)**, and I've imported all packages including **GunJS** and **SEA**, however, when I run the app, I get the error that dynamic require is not supported by **Metro**. I checked the sea.js file and found that the devs use **require(arg)**, which is not supported by **React Native**. This is a huge bummer and I haven't found any workaround. *Is there any other way to access SEA?*

```
    import GUN from "gun";
    import "gun/sea";
    import { userContext } from "../global";

    export const gun = GUN();
```

The below snippet is the sea.js file, which uses dynamic require.

```
    /* UNBUILD */
      function USE(arg, req){
        return req? require(arg) : arg.slice? USE[R(arg)] : function(mod, path){
          arg(mod = {exports: {}});
          USE[R(path)] = mod.exports;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

We got this fixed in the latest GitHub main (hopefully published soon).

Thanks to Aethiop! Who also wrote a great tutorial on this:

https://github.com/aethiop/jot

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use SEA in react-native now  without wait the gun community to fix this problem do this build API with nodejs and install gun in after going in your react-native app call this API
see ex:

```js
//nodejs that manage sea so in my case I use auth feature  sea 

const fastify = require("fastify")();
const Gun = require('gun'); // in NodeJS 
require('./sea/sae');

const gun = new Gun ({
    peers: ['https://gun-serve.herokuapp.com/gun'],
     
   })  

const user = gun.user()
const ADDRESS = "0.0.0.0";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
fastify.get("/", function (req, reply) {
   reply.send("wellcome");
});

fastify.post('/userregist', async (request, reply) => {
  try {
  user.create(`${request.body.user}`,`${request.body.password}`, ({ err , pub}) => {
      if (err) {
         
   
        return reply.code(200).send({ "err": `${err}`})
      } else {
      
        
          return reply.code(200).send({"pub": `${pub}`})
      
      }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      request.log.error(error);
      return reply.send(500);
  }
      

})
    
fastify.post('/userlogin', async (request, reply) => {
  try{
  user.auth(`${request.body.user}`,`${request.body.password}`, ({ err, get,  }) => {
    if (err) {
     
       return reply.code(200).send({ "err": `${err}`})
    } else {
    
        console.log('joshau get', get)
       
       
        return reply.code(200).send({"pub": `${get}`})
     
    }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    request.log.error(error);
    return reply.send(500);
}

})

fastify.listen(PORT, ADDRESS, (err, address) => {
  if (err) {
     console.log(err);
     process.exit(1);
  }
});
```

so i call api my app like that:

```js
//my call api 
const loginRequest = async (email, password) => {
  try {
    return await fetch('https://locahost:3000/userlogin', {
      mode: 'no-cors', method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': ' application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
            user: email,
            password: password,
            
      }),
    })
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  }
};
// here is way i call it i comp
LoginRequest(email, password)
      .then((res)=> {
       
        res.json().then(function (text) {

          if(text.err){
             LOADING_STOP()
           
            alert(`${text.err}`)
            
            console.log('error message',text.err)
          }else{

            console.log('public key',text.pub)
          
           
            LOADING_STOP()
           
            navigation.replace("Dashboard");
          }
            
      }).catch((e)=> {
         LOADING_STOP()
       
        alert(e)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

put `import shim from "gun/lib/mobile"`
at the top of your file. (before the SEA import) :D !

```
import shim from "gun/lib/mobile"
import SEA from 'gun/sea'
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the latest version (0.2020.1235). They removed the mobile.js file from node_modules :(